# Java - any flaw(s) with using String instead of int/long to represent immutable fields?

Tags: java, performance, casting, finance, primitive

Fairly generic question because I'm afraid I don't have the best Java academic/theoretical fundamentals:

I work in a bank and we store/process lots of data. This takes the shape of account id, deal id, portfolio values, etc.

The goal is to take a request from an API or as a library, query a DB, perform some business transforms, and store to another DB.

1. Should the data types match the destination DB? I.e. use date objects when persisted as date. Long for IDs, double for decimals, string when varchar, etc..?
2. Do whatever is easier (often changing everything to strings) because of how the objects are handled in Java will have minimal performance ?

Thanks in advance for your time!

Comment: I think your question is just a little too broad.  If you could narrow it down to some specific example, we might be able to answer.

Comment: Pretty broad question, so here's a broad answer: pick the right datatype for the job. If you need immutability, use `final`. You probably also want to take a look at BigDecimal and BigInteger, because primitive types will not be sufficient when dealing with money.

Comment: Converting between numbers and strings is relatively expensive.   And in some cases lossey.

Answer (score 3):

As Floegipoky has pointed out, use `final` so you make primitives and most simple objects immutable de facto.

Note that doesn't work for Collections, because even when an Collection object may be declared final, that only means that you can change the Collection reference, but still you can change its items with the methods their provide.

For example:

```
final List<Integer> integers = new List();
// Do whatever operations you want with the list
integers.add(1);       // <- No error. The list content is mutable.
integers = new List(); // <- Compiler error. The `final` means we cannot change the reference variable to point to a different list object.
```

Will add an integer to that integers list despite being final, although you cannot change the reference itself.

What you can do in these cases is to convert the list to an unmodifiable one:

```
final List<Integer> integers = new List();
// Do whatever operations you want with the list
final List<Integer> integersInmutable = Collections.unmodifiableList(integers);
integers = null; // Better safe than sorry…
integersInmutable.add(1); // <- runtime exception 
integersInmutable = new List(); // <- compiler error
```

Probably there are other caveats, but remember that Java is an OOP language, so you can always create your own unmodifiable classes based on the ones that already exists. For example, if you want to restrict the operations you can do with a List, you can create your own list derivated from List or from AbstractList and override those methods you don't want to be used so they throw an exception for example.

Answer (score 1):

Converting everything into String (e.g. converting numeric data to String) before storing into the database and converting it back to the native Java types (e.g. converting String back to numeric type) will impact performance along with the potential of being a lossy conversion.

You should take a look at the documentation and recommended best practices of the database driver you plan to use in choosing the datatypes. For example, if you are using the JDBC driver, you will find the database vendor documenting a mapping table between the Java/JDBC datatypes and the corresponding database type. Such a mapping table would have factored in choices that give the best performance without conversion loss.

Hope this helps!